# 2D games on iOS

Tags: ios, 2d

This is something I've pondered/struggled with and would love to hear some opinions on.  I have a good deal of familiarity with the iOS sdk but not so much with the opengl related aspects and not really any with the various SDKs, especially game SDKs build to work on iOS.

If I want to create 2D games for iPhone/iPad, is it easy/better/practical to use some simple collection of iOS SDK objects such as the UIImageViews etc to build a plethora of sprites interacting on the screen, or much better to go with an SDK for that? I'm assuming that going with gl is overboard for 2d requirements, but please voice any dissent if I'm wrong there.

I'm mainly interested in what the quickest route to getting things done is, combined with the smallest requirements to ramp up on technologies.  Obviously if it is well worth it to use an SDK simply because it is cross platform for other OSs, that is reasonable to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using a framework on top of OpenGL can greatly increase productivity, maintainability and reduce programming errors.

Personally I work with [cocos2d-for-iphone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). It's written in Objective-C and is based on top of OpenGL. It was created with the aims to create 2D games and thus unlike UIKit or QuartzCore, it's designed for that. It provides a lot of convenience API to manage scenes or sprites, to create animations, etc. Or even libraries for the sounds for example.

There is a very good article which describes some open-source game engines available on iphone [here](http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/). It could help you in your search.